# mixin and append it to psuedo element using scss

Tags: css, scss-mixins

I have below mixin created in mixins.scss file.
working example of cheveron-circle-right as per [codepen](https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/gOegwJj)

```
@mixin custom-cheveron-cirle-right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    background-color:#0069AA;
    position:relative;
    &::after {
      position:absolute;
      top:4px;
      left:3px;
      width: 3px;
      height: 3px;
      border-top: 3px solid #fff;
      border-right: 3px solid #fff;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  }
```

Above `mixins` I am appending in existing `li:before` node as below

```
 li:before { @include custom-cheveron-cirle-right; 
    content:''; 
    float: left;
     margin-left: -.75rem;
     padding: .185rem 0 0 0;
     font-size: .75rem;
     transform: rotate(0.001deg);
 }
```

but when I am rendering it just does the rendering of the `circle` and does not render `arrow` inside `circle`, the basic purpose here is not to use the `font-awesome` library and need to have our own custom icon in place which are created using CSS and `mixins`.

Comment: You are missing the content property in the settings for the pseudo element.

Comment: you mean in mixin ? I already tried no luck

Comment: Could you update your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- you are missing `content:'';` in the `::after` inside mixin
- you are including your mixin (`@include`) inside `::before`, instead of the parent, which then generate invalid CSS `li::before::after`

**Note:**: changed the `li` to `div` to match your codepen HTML

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/dippas/pen/zYWNRRz)

```
@mixin custom-cheveron-cirle-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  background-color: #0069aa;
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
    border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

div {
  @include custom-cheveron-cirle-right;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    margin-left: -0.75rem;
    padding: 0.185rem 0 0 0;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    transform: rotate(0.001deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I am comparing, let me double check with my code and get back to you, btw thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply, I added comment in codepen, in div part of the .scss, describing my current structure. https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/ZExLxYX

Comment: I don't see any comments, you added `padding-left: 2rem;`  that ruins the layout

Comment: I can not add width and height to parent li as the content may be specific length to div, setting height and width on li causes distorted UI

Comment: https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/ZExLxYX, here it goes, sorry i did not save it

Comment: Please remember that li has content setting height and width causing issue

Comment: https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/ZExLxYX, with content

Comment: there is no `li` in your html

Comment: here is ul, li version of code https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/ZExLxYX

Comment: did you get what is an issue ?

Comment: here is a simplified/improved working version of your code, next time when asking question don't leave important things  https://codepen.io/dippas/pen/RwMKMaX

Comment: excellent sir, nice and thank you, what if I dont have span inside li just anchor tag, @inlcude will goto anchor tag ?, I will upvote this answer

Comment: yup that's right

Comment: for example for given  li content goes to second line, it gets distorted rest looks good, can you please help me here? https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/dymNmZx

Comment: You need to add `flex-shrink: 0`, in `::before`, but I've improved your code a bit more https://codepen.io/dippas/pen/QWmdmBq

Comment: that does help there but in other some li the '>' goes on top, I mean those li which has content goes to second line now circle is not shrinking but, arrow inside that goes to top

Comment: did you see my codepen ?? refresh the tab, or re-open it again, I fixed all of that when I said `but I've improved your code a bit more`

Comment: sure,it is working now! thanks a lot for saving my day.

Comment: btw why top is creating issue, I want to center icon in any case

Comment: if I keep top, li with more content, the '>' goes beyond circle

Comment: without `top` its centered. also further questions (as the ones you asked in this comments) should be done in another new question  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254814/op-keeps-asking-more-questions-based-on-a-single-question-which-was-answered-alr